# How can I access an object in NSMutablearray by Tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

I'm very new to Obj-C, so hopefully someone can lend a hand!

How can I access an object in NSMutablearray by Tag?

I am creating an if statement and I want it to check if an object is == to the object in an array with the tag "1".  Is something like this possible? (The capitalized words below are what I do not know how to say in Obj-C).....

```
if (starInArray == MYMUTABLEARRAY OBJECT WITH THE TAG "1") {
do something;
};
```

I know I can use [array objectAtIndex:i] but I can't use it because my array will keep removing objects as the game goes on, and I need to keep track of touches on specific objects as the game continues.

Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply iterate the array and compare each object against the one you have?

Comment: This seems like it could work...how would I write that out?  Sorry, very new!  This would work if I can iterate through the array by looking through the object's tag names.

Comment: Iterating through an array is pretty basic. If you don't know how yet, found yourself a good tutorial or do a little searching.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a NSPredicate.  Assuming each item in the array has a tag property.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == 1"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The result, `filteredArray`, will be an array of all items containing a tag property equal to 1.

Comment: That's something new!  But when I do starInArray == filteredArray, I get an error saying that I'm comparing distinct pointer types, CCSprite and NSArray.  (starInArray is a sprite) - i guess that changes things!

Comment: Look inside `filteredArray` for your object.  If there will only be on you can `starInArray == [filteredArray lastObject]`

Comment: Couldn't and shouldn't he be using NSMutableSet if the tag (key) is so important?

Answer (score 0):

Y can map your game object same tag as the index in your array.

For example, you can do this:

```
/// stars array
NSMutableArray *stars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

/// create stars
for(NSInteger i; i < NUM_STARS; i++)
{
   Star *star = [[Star alloc] init];
   star.tag = i; /// assume your star object has a property called tag
   [stars addObject:star];
}
```

Comment: The question is about finding an object in the array, not about creating the array.